# Max list size for scroller

Tags: android

I've implemented my own `HorizontalListView` and I'd like to use a `Scroller` to manage certain scroll events, such as flings. The `Scroller` `fling()` method requires me to provide the maximum X and Y size of my component, and so I come to a bit of a problem--what's the best way to calculate the size of my list?

I have thought of several approaches:

1) Max width is equal to the width of the elements of the list times the number of list elements. The problem with this is that they're variable width.

2) Create all the elements of the list on initial layout and calculate the maximum width. This seems terribly inefficient.

3) (the approach I've been using up until now) when a child is added to my `HorizontalListView` increment my `maxWidth`, and when a child is removed, decrement the `maxWidth`. I've been using this to limit the scrolling to the bounds of my list--if the last child has not been added, then the `maxWidth` is not relevant anyway and once the last child has been added, it's accurate. The problem is that when the list is flung, the `maxWidth` calculated in this manner may not be representative of the actual maximum size of the list.

Any other suggestions? Otherwise I might have to implement my own fling mechanism...

Comment: I'll probably stick to an average size using your approach number 1.

Comment: That's not a great approach--unfortunately the sizes can vary greatly, from 1 character TextViews to whole words.

Answer (score 0):

based on your comment I'll guess a another approach trying adjust between 1) efficient and 2) precision:

I understood from your comment that they would be `TextView` your adapter Views.
So you probably can calculate the total size using an approach like this:

```
int space = adapter.getCount() * textview.leftMargin + rightMargin + leftPadding + rightPadding;
float textsize = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++){
   textsize += adapter.getItem().toString().lenght();
}
textSize = textSize * "size of text in your XML. e.g. 14 for 14dp * scale factor"

int listSize = space + textSize;
```

it's certainly a bit slower than the 1), but you just have to go through all the items and count their chars, multiply by the char width and add paddings/margins.

Comment: But the chars are not uniform widths. I'd probably still have to measure all the TextViews. Maybe I could just create one TextView and iterate through all my Texts, updating the text in the temp TextView and remeasuring. Still, super hacky in case I ever go with something other than TextViews.